# Where is latest version of Windows 10 SDK available in Visual Studio 2017 Installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10-sdk

According to [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) Microsoft post about latest Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.132:

> > …. or you can install it by selecting this version of the Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17763.132) in the Visual Studio 15.8 Installer optional components.

But when I go to the installer of `VS2017 - ver 15.9.5` from `VS2017-->Tools-->Tools and Features`, I don't see the `Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.132` as shown in the image below:

**Question**: How can I install Win 10 SDK version 10.0.17763.132 from Visual Studio installer?

[image]